# Update statement to update two columns of a table using the next value of a column in same table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, unique-constraint

I have a table in which I want to update two columns. below is example:

Actual table:

```
Team    | PLAYERNUM|  NAME 
--------+----------+--------
A       |    1     |   ONE  | 
A       |    2     |   TWO  | 
A       |    3     |   THREE| 
B       |    1     |   FOUR | 
B       |    2     |   FIVE | 
B       |    3     |   SIX  |
```

Expected result:

```
Team    |PLAYERNUM |  NAME 
--------+----------+--------
A       |    1     |   ONE  | 
A       |    2     |   TWO  | 
A       |    3     |   THREE| 
A       |    4     |   FOUR | 
A       |    5     |   FIVE | 
A       |    6     |   SIX  |
```

unique constraint is enable on columns 'Team' and 'PLAYERNUM'. Now I want to update all the rows with Team as 'B' to 'A'. I'm getting a unique constraint violation error because the 'PLAYERNUM' are unique. Any clue on how to update Team B and PLAYERNUM to 4 5 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `common-table-expression` to with `row_number()` window analytic function to perform update operation :

```
update tab t
   set playernum = (
  with cte as (
    select t.*, row_number() over (order by Team,playernum) as rn
    from tab t 
  )
  select rn
    from  cte 
   where cte.team = t.team and cte.playernum = t.playernum
 ), team = 'A';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e321d775c56f0adce189955e17e46bba)</kbd>

*if only the column team is updated as team = 'A', you'd get primary key constraint violation error(try in the demo), but the above style yields no error.*